# How to get a different output?

Tags: python, list, output

I am new to python programming. I was trying to write a program to find how many 9s are present in the list.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrobX.png)

```py
seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 8, 13, 9, 12, 19]
n = 0
t = []
y = len(seq)
for x in range (0, y-1):
    if seq[x] == 9:
        n += 1
        t.append(x+1) 
    else: continue
print (n, "numbers of 9s are present at", t, "position" )'
```

output: 2 numbers of 9s are present at [5, 9] position

How i have write the program to get the output as "2 numbers of 9s are present at 5 and 9 position".

Comment: How about `' and '.join(map(str, t))` in place of `t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the list comprehension. `enumerate` return the element (`num`) of list and the index of element (`idx`) and if the element (`num`) is equal to 9 then the `positions` list will contain the `idx` as a string. The indexing starts from 1 (not 0) (`start=1`). You can get the number of 9s with `len(positions)` and you can join the element with `" and ".join(positions)`.

**Code:**

```
seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 8, 13, 9, 12, 19]
positions = [str(idx) for idx, num in enumerate(seq, start=1) if num == 9]
print("{} numbers of 9s are present at {} positions".format(len(positions), " and ".join(positions)))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
2 numbers of 9s are present at 5 and 9 positions
```

I guess it is the most elegant way to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
your_list = [4,5,6,7,9,6,7,9]
indexes = []
for i, num in enumerate(your_list, start=1):
    if num == 9:
        indexes.append(i)

def output_list(str_list):
    last_value = str_list[-1]
    first_indexes = str_list[:-1]
    first_indexes_str = ", ".join(first_indexes)
    if len(first_indexes) == 0:
        return f'{len(indexes)} numbers of 9s are present at {last_value} position'
    return f'{len(indexes)} numbers of 9s are present at {first_indexes_str} and {last_value} position'

print(output_list(indexes))
```

first empty list of the index list.

loop over the list and get the index by using `(enumerate)`.

if the num is nine append to the indexes list.

after that print by using the `f'...'` and print how much find and where.

and add the function that parses the data as wanted

Comment: I guess you have to do `indexes.append(i + 1)` to get desired result

Comment: Use `enumerate(your_list, start=1)`, so you'll get the right index directly.

Comment: Thank you. But it is giving similar output as i am getting from my program.

Comment: I thought you had problems with the algorithm and not the prints themselves

Answer (score 0):

Well, first make a for loop in your list, taking each element, then compare this element to 9 to see if it's a 9 or not. `compt` variable will count "9" encounters.

```
compt = 0
seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 8, 13, 9, 12, 19]    
for k in seq:
    if(k == 9):
        compt += 1
print(compt)
```

If you also want the index / position of nines founds, then do the same, looping on index, and keep an index list :

```
compt = 0
indexlist = []
seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 8, 13, 9, 12, 19]    
for k in range(0, len(seq)):
    if(seq[k] == 9):
        compt += 1
        indexlist.append(k)
print(str(compt) + " nines founds, in following positions : " + str(indexlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locate` present in `more_itertools` module

```
from more_itertools import locate

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 8, 13, 9, 12, 19]
indices = list(locate(arr, lambda a: a==9))
```

You can add `+1` to each element in the indices to get the position

Answer (score 0):

```
 seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 8, 13, 9, 12, 19]

 positions = [i + 1 for i in range(len(seq)) if seq[i] == 9]

 print(f"{len(positions)} numbers of 9s are present at {positions} position")
```

Comment: Maybe add some explanation?